# Arcpy strip '{ and ]' from list return

Tags: python, arcpy, python-addin

I have a static list that I would like to pull values from and use in a query. I can populate the list dynamically from the data but the set is quite large and I think having a static list from a csv would increase performatance. I cannot get Arc to accept the return from the input to the select by attribute clause.

```
class ComboBoxClass1(object):
    """Implementation for addin2_addin.combobox (ComboBox)"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.editable = True
        self.enabled = True
        self.dropdownWidth = 'W' * 16
        self.width = 'W' * 16
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
        self.mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
        self.df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

    def onSelChange(self, selection):
        selection = str(selection).replace("'[",'').replace("]'",'')
        layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(self.mxd, "block_cards", self.df)[0]
        a = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layer, "NEW_SELECTION", "town = '{}'".format(selection))
        self.df.extent = layer.getSelectedExtent()
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

    def onFocus(self, focused):
        fldName = "town"
        with open(r'towns_table.csv', 'rb') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            your_list = list(reader)


        layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(self.mxd, "block_cards", self.df)[0]
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layer, "CLEAR_SELECTION")
        self.items = sorted(list(your_list))
```

I have tried several things to strip the brackets from the return (in python everything comes back '[denver]') with no luck. i think thats the sticking point but i could be off on that.

Comment: Not sure why you have brackets in the first place, but if you're sure you'd like to strip the first and last characters, Python can 'slice' a string, as in [1:-1].

Comment: is it returning a list?  Why not just use `"NEW_SELECTION", "town = '{}'".format(selection[0]))`...Haha, fancy seeing you here Wayne!!

Comment: thanks for the responses fellas. the format selection returns ['Carbondale'] which will not work for a second query I am running. I have tried to slice but that doesnt appear to work either.

Comment: dont slice, use the index of the list like @crmackey suggests:  mylist[0] (for first item in the list)

Comment: I think you should be able to extract a code snippet (from the class that you are currently presenting), that works up to where you are stuck, so that there is a simpler test case for our volunteers to run and play with.  That code snippet should incorporate the advice offered so far as comments.